# Micronaut + GraalVM + Kotlin for Lambda Function with S3 Notification fails to run with error "Unconvertible input: null"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-lambda, micronaut, graalvm

I am using micronaut to create a kotlin project that can build to a native GraalVM image that I can upload as a lambda function on AWS. I want this lambda function to get triggereted on S3 Notification Event.

I went to micronaut.io, clicked launched and then tried to choose:

1. Function Application for Serverless
2. Features: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-s3-event-notification
3. Kotlin and Gradle Kotlin.

It generated some files that I have not changed except putting a simple hello world print.

The files are like so:

**FunctionlambdaRuntime.kt**

```
package com.example
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.models.s3.S3EventNotification;
import io.micronaut.function.aws.runtime.AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime
import java.net.MalformedURLException

class FunctionLambdaRuntime : AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent, S3EventNotification, Void?>()
{

    override fun createRequestHandler(vararg args: String?): RequestHandler<S3EventNotification, Void?> {
        return FunctionRequestHandler()
    }
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(vararg args: String) {
            try {
                FunctionLambdaRuntime().run(*args)
            } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FunctionRequestHandler.kt**

```
package com.example
import io.micronaut.function.aws.MicronautRequestHandler
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.models.s3.S3EventNotification;
class FunctionRequestHandler : MicronautRequestHandler<S3EventNotification, Void?>() {
    override fun execute(input: S3EventNotification): Void? {
        println("Hello, world!")
        return null
    }
}
```

Then I use `./gradlew buildNativeLambda` to bulid the image in a zip file. I upload this file to the AWS lambda function, which is a custom runtime on Amazon Linux 2 with handler set to `com.example.FunctionRequestHandler`. I then try to create a S3 Notification test from the Lambda console like this one:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "example-bucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "test%2Fkey",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unconvertible input: null"
}
```

I have also tried creating a real S3 notification event and then observe the CloudWatch logs for the "hello world" message but I still see in the logs "unconvertible input: null". I am not sure what's wrong. I have not changed anything except putting that print statement there.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

class FunctionLambdaRuntime : AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime<***APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent***, S3EventNotification, Void?>()

↓

class FunctionLambdaRuntime : AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime<***S3EventNotification, Void?***, S3EventNotification, Void?>()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).